# GA4 with Adobe AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, air, adobe, google-analytics-4

Did anyone successfully implement Google Analytics 4 in an Adobe AIR app?

We have an Adobe AIR application (for Windows desktop) which currently sends tracking data to Google Analytics, and it works fine: we get to see the result in Google Analytics dashboards as well as in DataStudio.
Google documentation explains how to move from GA to GA4, but it relies on javascript in webpages, which is not relevant to an Adobe AIR project.

We tried to change the endpoint API URL, the GA property ID, add the api_secret & measurement_id parameters. We still don't see any data in GA dashboards.
We don't really know if switching to GA4 is supposed to be this straightforward, or if it would require a deeper rework of our actionscript code to take into account the new GA4 features & requirements.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to this issue:

[Google Analytics 4 - Measurement Protocol API used without gtag.js or firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69105735/google-analytics-4-measurement-protocol-api-used-without-gtag-js-or-firebase)

GA4 seems to be very limiting compared to UA for non web and mobile apps; it seems to only support data from either the firebase or gtag SDKs or GTM (also web based). Apps such as desktop apps that previously used HTTP web requests via the Measurement Protocol are handicapped; it is only meant to augment the other data.

In my opinion this is a huge step back for GA.